# Save place in files but don't move the cursor to the saved position automatically

Tags: buffers, files, cursor, saveplace

I'd like to have a command that moves the cursor to the last position it was in when I left the buffer (either by killing it or by killing Emacs).

I know I can use saveplace.el to save the position for when I visit that file again, but then saveplace also takes the cursor to that position automatically, while I would like to leave the cursor at the beginning of the buffer, and move to the last position only when I want to do it, using a command. (Basically, like <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> does in Vim.)

Comment: Define "left the buffer". Did you kill it? Just switch to another buffer? Kill Emacs. The question is unclear. If you know *when* you want to save a position value (which is just a number), you can save it in a variable, using, for example, `save-hist-additional-variables`. And depending on the *when* you can use a particular hook - there are hooks for buffer switching, quitting Emacs, etc.

Comment: @Drew I mean when I kill Emacs or the buffer.

Comment: Please put that info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 2):

I have written something that after some quick testing seems to be working.

`save-place-mode` does the automatic restoring of the cursor position by adding `save-place-find-file-hook` – which takes the cursor to the saved position – to `find-file-hook`. To change the behaviour so that the restoring can be done on demand, I removed `save-place-find-file-hook` from the hook and wrapped it in an interactive function.

```
(save-place-mode)
(remove-hook 'find-file-hook #'save-place-find-file-hook)
(remove-hook 'dired-initial-position-hook #'save-place-dired-hook)

(defun goto-saved-place ()
  (interactive "^")
  (save-place-find-file-hook))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c '") #'goto-saved-place)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the current position in a variable of your choosing and save that variable persistently. Put a function that sets the variable value on `kill-buffer-hook`, since you say (in a comment) that you want to do this just before killing the buffer.  Or on `kill-emacs-hook`.

You can add your variable for this to `savehist-additional-variables`, and use `savehist-mode` to save such variables.  You can also invoke `savehist-save` explicitly in your hook function.

Comment: I think the best approach is to make that variable an alist, but I don't know how to do that. saveplace already builds an alist of files and positions, but I need to know how to disable the automatic restoring of the position on the buffer and make it available on demand. So, basically, I need some more help: either on building an alist or on fixing saveplace's behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to read the alist, too. How about `(goto-char (cdr (assq <filename> <alist>)))`?

Comment: Not too sure what you're asking now. I suggest you formulate it as a separate question. Any variable can have an [alist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) as its value. My suggestion is not about saveplace but about savehist: saving a variable value persistently. And yes, you can use `goto-char` after getting the position associated with the file name.